# rails render layout as file (not partial)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I need to do the following:

```
render partial: 'my_partial', layout: 'my_layout'
```

but layout in this case is a view, not a partial.
I have a layout defined in:

```
app/views/layouts/participant.html.haml # view
```

But Rails is looking for a

```
app/views/layouts/_participant.html.haml # partial
```

I tried full path

```
render partial: 'my_partial', layout: 'full_path/to/my_layout'
```

but it still looks for a partial.

How do I do that?

Comment: Its very unclear, can you explain the question in more details?

Comment: You're still doing `render :partial`, can you try: `render layout: 'full_path/to/my_layout'`

Comment: @martincarlin87 it will work, but I need to render the partial WITH  layout.. It works if I have layout file as partial, but I have to have it as file (without  `_` part in file name)..

Comment: @AndreyDeineko, ah, sorry, I misunderstood. I've never used it but you could try `render file: '/path_to/my_partial', layout: true`. Docs here - http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render

Comment: @martincarlin87 actually as I've written in my question I've done that and Rails is still looking for a partial in place of my_layout..

Comment: @AndreyDeineko hmm unless I've missed it, I don't see `render: file` anywhere in the question.

Comment: ooh, you changed something in the comment. let my try it!

Comment: @martincarlin87 and it worked, please post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: excellent, glad it worked, just posted an answer, cheers.

Comment: @martincarlin87 I am really appreciated man ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used it but you could try:

```
render file: '/path_to/my_view', layout: true
```

[Docs here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render).